# Flux Utils MapStore

Tags: reactjs, flux

Do I have to manually define my initial state as an immutable map when using Flux's [MapStore](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html#mapstore-k-v) Util. Or can I return an object and it'll internally make that into an immutable map ?

ie.

```
getInitialState() {

    return Immutable.fromJS({
       hello: Ted
    });
}
```

vs

```
getInitialState() {

    return {
       hello: Ted
    };
}
```

I'm halfway into a project with the later, and have just realised that my state thinks its changing more than it is :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, turns out its up to you to return an `Immutable.Map` in the `getInitialState` function.